# Flutter: How to merge two StreamBuilder and show the output in a card

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm kinda stuck with what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to merge my two Stream Builder to show the output as one in a card. In my first StreamBuilder thats where I'm getting some infos of the user like the info that he posted, what they need like that. And in my 2nd StreamBuilder thats where I get his/her name, contacts like that. Is it possible to merge it as one? so I'll get the data as one also.

This is how I use my StreamBuilders.

1st stream:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: db.collection('HELP REQUEST').where('Type_OfDisaster', isEqualTo: '[Drought]').snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return Column(
        children: snapshot.data.documents
          .map((doc) => buildItem(doc))
          .toList()
      );
    } else {
      return Container(
        child: Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator()
        )
      );
    }
  }
);
```

2nd Stream:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: db.collection('USERS').where('User_ID', isEqualTo: widget.Uid).snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return Column(
        children: snapshot.data.documents
          .map((doc) => buildItem(doc))
          .toList()
      );
    } else {
      return Container(
        child: Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator()
        )
      );
    }
  }
);
```

Here is where I output the data I get in the stream builder:

```
Container buildItem(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
final _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
final _height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
return Container(
  child: Card(
    elevation: 5,
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20, right: 20),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 30,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  ),
                  Text('Name: '),
                  Text(
                    '${doc.data['Name_ofUser']}',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Container(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Date:'),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        '${doc.data['Help_DatePosted']}',
                        maxLines: 1,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Location:'),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        '${doc.data['Help_Location']}',
                        maxLines: 2,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                  child: Text('Description:'),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text(
                    '${doc.data['Help_Description']}',
                    maxLines: 3,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                child: Container(
                  height: _height * 0.05,
                  width: _width * 0.20,
                  child: FlatButton(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius:
                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))),
                    color: Color(0xFF121A21),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _viewingRequest(doc.data);
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'View',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 12,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
 );
}
```

Is it possible to do it? Please help me.

Comment: If an answer has fixed you issue, remember to mark it as correct. This will help other users I. The future.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the snapshots without using a StreamBuilder directly, like this:

```
List<HelpRequestsPlusUsers> helpRequestsPlusUsers = [];
List<User> allUsers = [];
List<HelpRequest> helpRequests = [];

@override
void initState() {
  db.collection('USERS').where('User_ID', isEqualTo: widget.Uid).snapshots().listen((snapshot){
    allusers = snapshot.data.documents;
    mergeUsersWithHelpRequests();
  });
  db.collection('HELP REQUEST').where('Type_OfDisaster', isEqualTo: '[Drought]').snapshots().listen((snapshot){
    helpRequests = snapshot.data.documents;
    mergeUsersWithHelpRequests();
  });
  super.initState();
}

void mergeUsersWithHelpRequests(){
  // Run the code to merge your allUsers and helpRequests data into a helpRequestsPlusUsers List
}
```

**Widget**

```
 Widget _buildHelpRequestsPlusUsersWidget (){
   if (helpRequestsPlusUsers.isNotEmpty) {
     return ListView.builder(
       itemBuilder: (context, index){
         return buildItem(helpRequestsPlusUsers[index]);
       }
     );
   } else {
     return Container(
       child: Center(
         child: CircularProgressIndicator()
       )
     );
   }
 }
```

Comment: I see this will be a good answer sir, but is it possible to do with stream builder? I use stream builder to get the data in real time so that it wont buff when I go to is page.

Comment: The solution I have given you works exactly the same way. It will not be slower. It just moves the listener away from a display Widget and gives you more control.

Comment: Your 2 streams have different kinds of data. If you show us the code that would merge the help requests with users, we can make it work.

Comment: Oh okay sir. But can you help me in how will I merge the data in void mergeUsersWithHelpRequests()? I'm kinda lost hehe.

Comment: I actually dont have two streams working yet sir. I only have one. I just showed two stream builders to show what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I added the code where and how I output the data. I output in a card. but in my code I only use one stream. now the question is, if I can use two streams at once and output it in my card.

Comment: To answer that question we need more information. Are you using streams because you want your data to be updated in real time? Because if not, instead of streams you should just do normal queries, join the data, and display it on the Card. If you do need them to be real time, then either you attempt something similar to the code I shared, or you may have to change the architecture of your Firestore collections.

Comment: I'm actually using the streambuilder to make the data real time sir. I came out with this idea because the way I created my architecture in Firestore is kinda different. I'm having problems if I do some edit in the user profile. So, thats why now I'm trying to do a two stream builder so If I edit some data in the USERS collection, it will directly show the change.

Comment: Ok, I understand now what you are trying to do. My approach still works though. If you have a List of HelpRequests, your HelpRequest has the user id and you are getting the user data from the User stream, then you can merge them as I was suggesting. You only display the data the first time once your merge your list HelpRequest with the data with the users. After that you keep listening to changes in either. Whenever you get a new snapshot from HelpRequests, you go through the users and update them in the list, if you get a new push from Users you update the users List and run again the merge.

Comment: Yes sir hehe the problem is just I dont understand yet how to implement the code you've given to my code hehe.